# Try and except returns error, however when run without, no error occurs?

Tags: python, tkinter, try-catch

Here's the code giving me issues:

```
    def connect(self):
    self.chatlog['state'] = NORMAL
    self.chatlog.insert(END, ("===ATTEMPTING TO CONNECT TO SERVER\n"))
    self.chatlog['state'] = DISABLED
    self.chatlog.yview(END)
    try:
        s.connect((host,port))
        self.chatlog['state'] = NORMAL
        self.chatlog.insert(END, ("===CONNECTED TO SERVER\n"))
        self.chatlog['state'] = DISABLED
        self.chatlog.yview(END)
        self.conn=True
        print("Connected")

    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        self.chatlog['state'] = NORMAL
        self.chatlog.insert(END, ("===SERVER COULD NOT BE FOUND\n" + "===PLEASE MAKE SURE THE SERVER IS ON, AND YOU'RE CONNECTED TO THE NETWORK\n"))
        self.chatlog['state'] = DISABLED
        self.chatlog.yview(END)
    else:
        self.chatlog['state'] = NORMAL
        self.chatlog.insert(END, ("===THERE'S AN ERROR WITH THE PROGRAM\n" + "===PLEASE TURN IT OFF AND ON AGAIN\n"))
        self.chatlog['state'] = DISABLED
        self.chatlog.yview(END)
```

When I connect to a server, it both connects (the "try" section completes fine, the print statement occurs) however the "else" section also occurs. I can't seem to find why. Does anyone have any idea what's causing this?

EDIT: I should say that when I remove the "else:" section, it works fine as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are trying to catch all exceptions here, but that's not the correct syntax.

The correct way to do it would be:

```
try:
   # do something dangerous
except ConnectionRefusedError:
   # handle known error
except:
   # handle unknown error
```

`else` in this case means that the code will be executed if no errors occur.

Comment: Avoid the use of bare `except` -- it will catch things like `SystemExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt` you probably don't want to catch. Instead, use `except Exception` to catch all remaining exceptions.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Answered the question and helped hugely.

Answer (score 1):

The `else` part of a `try: except: else: finally:` block is similar to the `else` in an `if: else:`, effectively:

```
if someerror:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

The `else` block runs when *no error is raised* from the `try` block. Using this block allows you to minimise the code in the `try` block; in your case:

```
try:
    s.connect((host,port))           
except ConnectionRefusedError:
    self.chatlog['state'] = NORMAL
    self.chatlog.insert(END, ("===SERVER COULD NOT BE FOUND\n" + "===PLEASE MAKE SURE THE SERVER IS ON, AND YOU'RE CONNECTED TO THE NETWORK\n"))
    self.chatlog['state'] = DISABLED
    self.chatlog.yview(END)
else:
    self.chatlog['state'] = NORMAL
    self.chatlog.insert(END, ("===CONNECTED TO SERVER\n"))
    self.chatlog['state'] = DISABLED
    self.chatlog.yview(END)
    self.conn=True
    print("Connected")
```